# How to consume C# DataTable in php e javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, php, asp.net

i'm working on a html/javascript/php application that call a c# web service. The web service built in c# retrieve data from mysql and returns a DataTable.

I'm calling a php file from ajax:

```
define(["jquery"], function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/ajaxcall/getAllAziende.php",
      DataType : 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
      console.log(xhr.statusText);
      console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(error);
    },
      failure: function(errMsg) {
                console.log("failure" + errMsg);
      }
   })
  })
});
```

This file call the web service:

```
<?php
   $client = new SoapClient('http://192.168.0.5/pass_app/WebService1.asmx?wsdl');

   $result = $client->getAllAziende();

   $decresult = json_decode(json_encode($result), True);
   $out = $decresult['getAllAziendeResult'];
print_r($out);

   $output = json_encode($result);
   echo $output;
?>
```

the print_r returns:

```
 [
{
  "ragione_sociale": "cinciallegraSRL",
  "via": null,
"cap": null,
"localita": null,
"provincia": null,
"telefono": null,
"fax": null,
"id_settore": null,
"id_attivita": null,
"note": null,
"id": 1
},
{
"ragione_sociale": "dwdwwdw",
"via": "",
"cap": "",
"localita": "",
"provincia": "",
"telefono": "",
"fax": "",
"id_settore": "",
"id_attivita": "",
"note": "",
"id": 2
},
{
"ragione_sociale": "pippo",
"via": "pluto",
"cap": "pape",
"localita": "",
"provincia": "",
"telefono": "",
"fax": "",
"id_settore": "",
"id_attivita": "",
"note": "",
"id": 4
}
]
```

I dont' know hot to consume this result in javascript, at the moment console.log(data) returns:

```
{"getAllAziendeResult":"[\n  {\n    \"ragione_sociale\": \"cinciallegraSRL\",\n    \"via\": null,\n    \"cap\": null,\n    \"localita\": null,\n    \"provincia\": null,\n    \"telefono\": null,\n    \"fax\": null,\n    \"id_settore\": null,\n    \"id_attivita\": null,\n    \"note\": null,\n    \"id\": 1\n  },
\n  {\n    \"ragione_sociale\": \"dwdwwdw\",\n    \"via\": \"\",\n    \"cap\": \"\",\n    \"localita\": \"\",\n    \"provincia\": \"\",\n    \"telefono\": \"\",\n    \"fax\": \"\",\n    \"id_settore\": \"\",\n    \"id_attivita\": \"\",\n    \"note\": \"\",\n    \"id\": 2\n  },
\n  {\n    \"ragione_sociale\": \"pippo\",\n    \"via\": \"pluto\",\n    \"cap\": \"pape\",\n    \"localita\": \"\",\n    \"provincia\": \"\",\n    \"telefono\": \"\",\n    \"fax\": \"\",\n    \"id_settore\": \"\",\n    \"id_attivita\": \"\",\n    \"note\": \"\",\n    \"id\": 4\n  }\n]"}
```

Can somebody help me please? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're seeing?

Comment: I don't know what is the best way to consume a DataTable in PHP e Javascript, so I don't kown if I'm working right. If I add the instruction json =JSON.parse(data) I get an error:  Unexpected string in JSON.